# XSS recommendation: Use innerText\textContent instead of innerHTML

Tags: javascript, css, web-component

I have created a Web Component for a requirement and I have received a `The best way to handle this is by not injecting untrusted strings in this way. Instead, use node.innerText or node.textContent to inject the string- the browser will not parse this string at all, preventing an XSS attack.` code review comment. I am still thinking about how to replace `innerHTML` to `innerText` or `textContent`.

Would the community have an input?

```
import RealBase from '../real-base';
import productCardTitleCss from '../../../css/_product-card-title.scss?inline';
import baseCss from '../../../css/_base.scss?inline';
const ESAPI = require('node-esapi');
class RealProductCardTitle extends RealBase {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.defaultClass = 'real-product-card-title';
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    this.render();
  }
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['heading', 'form'];
  }
  get heading() {
    return this.getAttribute('heading') || '';
  }
  set heading(value) {
    this.setAttribute('heading', value ? ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(value) : value);
  }
  get form() {
    return this.getAttribute('form') || '';
  }
  set form(value) {
    this.setAttribute('form', value ? ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(value) : value);
  }
  attributeChangedCallback() {
    this.render();
  }
  render() {
    const {
      heading,
      form,
    } = this;
    this.classList.add('real-block');
    this.classList.add(this.defaultClass);
    if (!this.shadowRoot) {
      this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    }
    //Recommendation for this line below
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
      <style>
        ${productCardTitleCss}
        ${baseCss}
      </style>
      <real-heading 
        class="real-product-card-title-heading" 
        input="${heading}">
      </real-heading>
      <div 
        class="real-product-card-title-attributes real-inline-block">
        ${form}
      </div>`;
  }
}
window.customElements.define('real-product-card-title', RealProductCardTitle);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: thanks @Konrad, so instead of using the shadowRoot, just create an element with inline styling and child elements(real-heading)\custom divs?

Comment: `ShadowRoot` inherits `Node` so you can `.appendChild` and such like any other node (aside from the restrictions shadow nodes have). Create your elements and append them to `.shadowRoot`.

Comment: I don't get why you are using `ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML` to store attribute values.

Comment: Explain the Why?! You read some place you shouldn't use ``innerHTML`` ? You have an ``open`` shadowRoot, anyone can "get in" and inject whatever they want. The **X** in XSS is for **Cross-site**. Where is ``innerHTML`` mentioned in: [How to secure Front End code from Cross-Site-Scripting](https://www.resources.hacware.com/how-to-secure-frontend-code-from-cross-site-scripting) ??